# adapt\adjust site to fit client resolution

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We have a publishing page in SP2010 where a user has added content in way of text and images. He has done this on a 1920x1080 resolution screen and it looks fine in this resolution. When clients on smaller resolutions loads the page the text and images are too large and ultimately make the experience poor. How can this be addressed in the easiest manner?

Comment: Make the layout responsive with CSS Media Queries

Comment: I have a basic knowledge of CSS as in changing\hiding stuff etc. have you any existing code snippets that can be applied to my scenario or would it all be bespoke to my needs? Thanks

Comment: No code snippets, it is pointless teaching you how to steer to the left when it is important to learn how to drive;  Learn wat CSS Media Queries are and you will be able to create any code snippets you need.

Answer (score 0):

Using media queries you can target your users' device widths directly.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp